# Add variable : 1 Week ago

Tags: customization, filters, variables, code

Could you explain to me how add filter date : "1 week ago"

Thanks for your help

```
/* Variables from the widget settings. */

        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        $number = $instance['number'];

        $checkbox = $instance['checkbox'];

        $top_popular_posts = new WP_Query('showposts=' . $number . '&orderby=rand&order=DESC');


        if ($top_popular_posts->have_posts()) :



        echo $before_widget;
```

Comment: Is this code you can edit, or do you need to filter the results from a separate theme/plugin?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in WordPress via:

```
 <?php human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?>
```

Refernece: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff